# How to use BITS data type in Snmp set method in WebNMS? Is it same as Octet String?

Tags: java

Reference : https://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/using_mibs_in_applns/bits_datatype.html

I have read this on WebNMS site, but i need more details to use Snmp Set method for BITS datatype.

Answer (score 0):

BITS is a textual convention defined , and its underlying type is OCTET STRING. So when you try to use SET operation you should send the raw bytes as OCTET STRING. But of course you need to carefully encode the bytes if the library/tool you use does not provide you wrappers to manipulate BITS types.